# How to delete all rows from datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, rowstate

I want to delete all rows from datatable with rowstate property value Deleted.

```
DataTable dt;
dt.Clear(); // this will not set rowstate property to delete.
```

Currently I am iterating through all rows and deleting each row.

Is there any efficient way?
I don't want to delete in SQL Server I want to use DataTable method.

---

Comment: You need to provide more details; what database do you use, and what language?

Comment: I am using C# and SQL Server database.

Answer (score 5):

We are using this way:

```
for(int i = table.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
    if ( row.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted ) { table.Rows.RemoveAt(i); }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the only better way 

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  row.Delete();
}

Comment: @meetjaydeep: If you do foreach, you can not change the collection. But RemeoveAt() changes collection, so foreach will be throw exception. So it's not solution.

Answer (score 3):

This will satisfy any FK cascade relationships, like 'delete' (that DataTable.Clear() will not):

```
DataTable dt = ...;
// Remove all
while(dt.Count > 0)
{
     dt.Rows[0].Delete();
}
```

Comment: I may have +1'ed too soon. This does not always work. This is vulnerable to an infinite loop. It seems like .Delete() doesn't always get rid of a row. It seems to merely mark a row's RowState as Deleted in some cases, without ever actually deleting them. This appears to be related to whether the row was created directly or had been added through a database call.

Answer (score 2):

```
dt.Rows.Clear();
dt.Columns.Clear();   //warning: All Columns delete
dt.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

I typically execute the following SQL command:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an SQL Server database, I would advocate simply executing the SQL command `"DELETE FROM " + dt.TableName`.

Comment: I want to delete from DataTable and it should update the rowstate.

Comment: it's a bad idea to do it using dynamic sql. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#good_practices

Answer (score 0):

I would drop the table, fastest way to delete everything. Then recreate the table.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stored procedure on the SQL Server db that deletes all the rows in the table, execute it from your C# code, then requery the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I settled on in my own code after searching for this question, taking inspiration from Jorge's answer.

```
DataTable RemoveRowsTable = ...;
int i=0;
//Remove All
while (i < RemoveRowsTable.Rows.Count)
{
     DataRow currentRow = RemoveRowsTable.Rows[i];
     if (currentRow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
     {
         currentRow.Delete();
     }
     else
     {
         i++;
     }
}
```

This way, you ensure all rows either get deleted, or have their DataRowState set to Deleted.

Also, you won't get the InvalidOperationException due to modifying a collection while enumerating, because `foreach` isn't used. However, the infinite loop bug that Jorge's solution is vulnerable to isn't a problem here because the code will increment past a DataRow whose DataRowState has already been set to Deleted.